# Finding the top categories of a column value based on the other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Finding the top categories of a column value based on the other column
DF :

```
nationality age card    category    amount
India   Young   AAA     Garment     200
India   Young   AAA     Dining      100
India   Young   BBB     Garment     400
Aus     Adult   BBB     Grocery     200
US      Adult   CCC     Beverage    100
India   Student CCC     Beverage    50
India   Adult   AAA     Grocery     1000
```

I want to use the column `Amount` and sort the value which is higher, this should also add up the amount, if the category, card, nationality and age is the same and return the top category.

Below is the sample data frame of the output i want.

Output:

```
nationality age    card Top1 category   Top2 category   Top3category
India      young    AAA Garment             Dining        NAN
India      Adult    AAA Grocery              NAN          NAN
India      student  CCC Beverage             NAN          NAN
Aus        Adult    BBB Grocery              NAN          NAN
US         Adult    CCC Beverage             NAN          NAN
```

For India, young, AAA, Garment, my amount is higher and it became the top category. Similarly for the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['sort_order'] = (df.sort_values(['nationality', 'age', 'card', 'amount'], ascending=False)
                      .groupby(['nationality', 'age', 'card'])
                      .cumcount())
df.set_index(['nationality', 'age', 'card', 'sort_order'])['category'].unstack().reset_index()
```

By sorting and then using [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), you get a per group order of categories (by amount). Then the [`df.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) pivots the table in the way you want. Of course, you can rename the columns later if desired.

Output:

```
#sort_order nationality      age card         0       1
#0                  Aus    Adult  BBB   Grocery     NaN
#1                India    Adult  AAA   Grocery     NaN
#2                India  Student  CCC  Beverage     NaN
#3                India    Young  AAA   Garment  Dining
#4                India    Young  BBB   Garment     NaN
#5                   US    Adult  CCC  Beverage     NaN
```